# How to find the value of String of a particular Pattern in java?

Tags: java, regex

In my page I have a several values having same pattern like `${rate+0.0020D2},${rate-0.4002D3},${rate+0.2003D4}` .

Basically the pattern is `${[rate][+ or - sign][a neumeric value ][D2 or D3 or D4]}`.

So I want to find all the values having these pattern in my jsp and want to store them in array.

Which regex pattern has to apply to find out value of this pattern.

Comment: You only want  the `0.0020D2` part right?

Comment: no i want whole value like for ${rate+0.0020D2} i want to get rate+0.0020D2. problem is  "+" "0.0020" and "D2" can b change so ow can i get all the values similar to this pattern

Answer (score 4):

There are probably better ways to do this, but this is my basic take on it...

```
String regExp = "\\$\\{rate[+-]\\d+(\\.\\d+)?D[0-9]\\}";
String value = "${rate+0.0020D2},banana,${rate-0.4002D3},${rate+0.2003D4},${rate+bananD4},${rate+.123.415D4}";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regExp);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);

String match = null;

List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>(5);
while (matcher.find()) {

    int startIndex = matcher.start();
    int endIndex = matcher.end();

    match = matcher.group();
    matches.add(match);

}
String[] results = matches.toArray(new String[0]);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(results));
```

Which will output

```
[${rate+0.0020D2}, ${rate-0.4002D3}, ${rate+0.2003D4}]
```

Comment: thanks mate !! can you please share the book or links  to learn regex patterns ?

Comment: I tend to refer to [this one](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) the most and any regular expression testers I can find, like [this](http://regexpal.com/) and SO of course

Comment: @vks I'm guessing it should be `[0-9\.]` :P, discounting for values which be in the form of `${rate+sometingD4}`...

Comment: @vks No argument here, just use to using `[0-9]` which is probably bad of me

Comment: @vks I was just hacking things into the tester ;), I had `rate` in an optional group earlier :P

Comment: "Hand commence docking with face"

Comment: Ok one last question before we can both leave :P is `{` required to be escaped in java?

Comment: Yes, otherwise it seems to throw *"Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 1"*

Comment: Thanks for all the nudges +1 to you as well :)

Comment: @madprogrammer if instead of ${rate+0.0020D2} test is rate+0.0020D2 then this regex pattern will be right ?? String regExp = "\\rate[+-]\\d+(\\.\\d+)D[0-9]\\";

Answer (score 2):

```
\${(rate[+-]\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:D2|D3|D4))}
```

Try this.See demo.Grab the `group 1`.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/12